# Router level filtering on home network

Tags: network

I want to block some part of a website or some videos from dailymotion or other site video sites.

**Type of network**

I have 7-8 devices(PCs, Mobiles, iPhones & tablets) all connected to a router ([Tenda W150d](http://www.tenda.cn/tendacn/product/show.aspx?productid=389)) with wire or with wifi. I dont have a seperate server like offices to control traffic.

**Problems**

- **I can** block websites on a single pc by some software but **can't** do that on mobile devices.
- I can not use a separate server turned on 24 hour

**Note:**

- I can buy a new router with reasonable price ($40-$50), suggest me if any of [these](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/187-1618518-5654624?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=router) can do what i want.
- This [link](http://lifehacker.com/344765/turn-your-60-router-into-a-user-friendly-super-router-with-tomato) seems good and i can afford it but not sure if it blocks urls.

Comment: What router do you currently have?

Comment: @eric_lagergren I have Tenda W150d

Comment: DNS providers can block sites, and you can set up your router to use those DNS services. Would that work for you?

Comment: DNS can block complete domains. In some cases i want to block some urls of webs like http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1yulfi_sharapova-the-day-after_sport not whole site

Answer (score 1):

Blocking some part of a website is easy with software like privoxy, or you can ban entire domains with dnsmasq. Both are available for most, if not all, open source router firmwares, like TomatoUSB or DD-WRT. For a good router, I recommend something like the Asus RT-N66U.

Comment: Can EasyTomato block specific part of url?